# Dash Button indicator Light

Tags: aws-iot, aws, amazon-iot-button

I have some Amazon Dash buttons that I want to use for multiple different scenarios, I don't know quite what yet, but I am unable to find a good way to make the indicator light turn green after I have pushed it.

I am aware that Amazon has a more expensive version of the button that can do this, I am going to buy one to play with, but I want to get this working if possible.

I found [this](https://github.com/ide/dash-button/issues/59) conversation and I looked at the links that are referenced and just like the comment says it is just not a very good way to do things.

I have some c# running as a service on my computer and all it is doing, for now, is looking for MAC address then logging when that happened.

I don't know much about web request stuff, but I am willing to really dig into it, as long as I don't have to do something like put custom firmware on my router.

I am using PacketDotNet and SharpPcap in my c# solution.

How do I return the 200 response, or anything else, to the Amazon Dash button to make the indicator turn green?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start by saying I've not looked at one of these in person yet,

But intercepting the call to the Amazon backend and responding to trigger the light is going to be tricky.

I fully expect these devices to be hitting HTTPS endpoints (I really hope they are) in AWS which means that even if you set up a firewall rule to redirect the request to something local it would need to respond with a matching TLS certificate.

You'll need to use something like wireshark to grab a button push to double check

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping that this wasn't the answer, and I haven't check wireshark to verify, but it does seem to make sense and go along with other things I've read online. Thank you for your help.